# how to host my WebSocket on IONOS hosting or VPS

Tags: kotlin, websocket, hosting, vps, ionos

I'm a newbie, I'll make an "uber" application like this https://github.com/CristianFernandoRomero1/ridesharing-uber-lyft-app

But I don't know how I can upload the WebSocket to a server, and what kind of server
Please help me

Pd: the websocket is "dummy" in the files, and I need to upload it to a server (hosting, vps, IONOS wordpress hosting) I don't know lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no code for WebSocket server in the GitHub repository.
That app(in repository) running with simulator.

So if you want run it with real server, you need to implement yourself and deploy(Any service you can use.)